# Proxmox assing public ip-address to container

Tags: linux, linux-networking, proxmox, containers

I wanted to assign a separate public IP-address to my container on Proxmox. My Network Interface looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens3
iface ens3 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static

    #Main public ip-address assigned to proxmox host
    address 91.xxx.xxx.xxx

    #Gateway from the SCP
    netmask 255.255.252.0
    gateway 91.xxx.xxx.1

    bridge_ports ens3
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 1

    #Same as the gateway
    pointopoint 91.xxx.xxx.1

    #My additional ip-address
    #Gateway is set to my Proxmox host public ip-address
    up route add -net 188.xx.xx.xx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 91.xxx.xxx.xxx vmbr1

#Used by my lxfc container on proxmox
auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static

    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    #NAT
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.1/24' -o vmbr1 -j MASQUERADE
    iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.1/24' -o vmbr1 -j MASQUERADE
```

My Container is configured to:

```
IPv4: 192.168.0.2/24
GW: 192.168.0.1
```

But when I try to ping google.com it says

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Its unclear what you want, if you want to assign a public ip to a Container, Add an interface, if Resolution is not working check /etc/resolv.conf however it is always a good Thing to host bind9 on the host to have a dns source dod you try ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Additionally you add and remove in the same the nat role, dont forget to add on the - A post-up and on - D post-down - take a Look at https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#_routed_configuration this worked for me

Comment: @djdomi I want to assign a public ip to a Container. With post-up and post-down it works now but I can't access the ip from outside.

Comment: You added an additionally interface and you cant ping the ip, is this right? Can you ping it from the host and from the vm itself?

Comment: please submit your New config, since it may make Things different and help US to Support you, however this is also one Projekt i need to do on my own Equipment

Comment: how should I submit my new config? Cloud we go in a live chat please since it is very difficult to understand this problem in a forum.

Comment: Sure, join me at telegram @ https://t.me/DoMeLe